# Visualizing radius, inner radius, inner diameter in a set

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I was studying the paper “An improved bound for the Shapley-Folkman theorem” (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmateco.2020.04.003), and had trouble visualizing these concepts (on the first page of the paper):

(For any subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$, $\operatorname{co}X$ denotes its convex hull).

For any nonempty subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$, define the *diameter* of $S$ by $$\operatorname{diam}(S):=\sup_{x,y{\in}S}\Vert{x-y}\Vert$$
define the *radius* of $S$ by
$$\operatorname{rad}(S):=\inf_{y{\in}\mathbb{R}^m}\sup_{x{\in}S}\Vert{x-y}\Vert$$
define the *inner diameter* of $S$ by
$$\operatorname{indiam}(S):=\sup_{y{\in}\operatorname{co}S}\inf_{T{\subseteq}S:y{\in}\operatorname{co}T}\operatorname{diam}(T)$$
and define the *inner radius* of $S$ by
$$\operatorname{inrad}(S):=\sup_{y{\in}\operatorname{co}S}\inf_{T{\subseteq}S:y{\in}\operatorname{co}T}\operatorname{rad}(T)$$

(There seems to be a visualization of this on Wikipedia, but I don’t completely understand it: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapley%E2%80%93Folkman_lemma#Shapley%E2%80%93Folkman_theorem_and_Starr's_corollary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapley%E2%80%93Folkman_lemma#Shapley%E2%80%93Folkman_theorem_and_Starr%27s_corollary))

I understand that $\operatorname{diam}(S)$ is the maximum distance between any two arbitrary points $x$ and $y$ in a set. This is easy enough to visualize. However, it is quite tough for me to understand what $\operatorname{rad}(S)$, $\operatorname{indiam}(S)$, and $\operatorname{inrad}(S)$ mean, and to visualize them. Can I get some help on this?

Comment: Radius looks fairly intuitive, as the radius of the smallest hypersphere that encloses all the points

Comment: How do you arrive at that result? One source of confusion is, I don't understand how to evaluate the infimum with y being any point in m-dimensional Euclidean space. Could you please walk me through the process?

Comment: Given $y$, you have $\sup_{x{\in}S}\Vert{x-y}\Vert$ in effect being the distance from $y$ to the furthest element of $S$, i.e. the radius centred at $y$ of the smallest hypersphere containing all of $S$.   Then $\inf_{y{\in}\mathbb{R}^m}\sup_{x{\in}S}\Vert{x-y}\Vert$ involves in effect finding the $y$ which minimises this, i.e. the smallest hypersphere containing all of $S$ centred anywhere.  Since $S$ may be infinite, it uses $\inf$ and $\sup$ instead of $\min$ and $\max$ (for some such $S$ there may not be such a centre but there is a limit point which is more or less the same thing)

Comment: I think I understand radius now, thank you for the explanation. I was trying to understand inner radius. I can write out the definition in words: the inner radius of S is the radius of the sphere such that for any point y in the convex hull of S, the sphere contains a subset of S whose convex hull contains y. I don't understand this definition - wouldn't the radius and inner radius always be equal? I am having trouble thinking of a case where the radius and inner radius would be different.